# MassTransit DelayedRedelivery called consecutively?

Tags: masstransit

I set up MassTransit/RabbitMQ on StartUp class like the image below:

[image]

I expect: if the initial 5 immediate retries fail, the message will re-try an additional three times after 5, 15, and 30 minutes (the document mention [here](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#redelivery))

But, in fact, the consumer is triggered consecutively. It was called over and over again. Could you help me understand this scenario? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be a transport-level error, such as the delayed exchange plug-in not being installed.

The details of how to configure RabbitMQ for delayed exchange support are covered in [the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/scheduling/rabbitmq-delayed.html). Pay particular attention to the [delayed exchange plug-in](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/) link.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't install that plug-in. You save my day!